# String doesn't seem to return

Tags: c#, string, function

The string in `NewString` doesn't seem to return to `UserType()` function. Is it wrong to declare that variable there? I want to return values to `UserType` so I can use it in another function like the `Vowel` function.

```cs
using System;

namespace prob1
{
    class Pogram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserType();
        }

        static void Menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nChoice of Operation:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Enter new/another string");
            Console.WriteLine("2.  Count vowels in string and display result");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Count consonants in string and display result");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Convert string to uppercase letters and display");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Convert string to lowercase letters and display");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Count number of words in the string");
            Console.WriteLine("7. Exit Program");
        }

        static void UserType()
        {
            string mainString = System.String.Empty;
            Menu();
            int menuChoice;
            menuChoice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            switch (menuChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    NewString(mainString);
                    
                    UserType();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Vowel(mainString);
                    UserType();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            
        }

        static string NewString(string mainString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a new string: ");
            mainString = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
      
            return mainString;
        }

        static void Vowel(string mainString)
        {
            int total = 0;
            var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
            
    
            for (int finder = 0; finder < mainString.Length; finder++)
            {
                if (vowels.Contains(mainString[finder]))
                {
                total++;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("total: " + total);
            
            Console.ReadKey(true);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `mainString` in the `NewString()` function is an input parameter. You probably meant for `NewString()` to return a value. Remove the parameter, and assign the result to the variable where you called it. `mainString = NewString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `NewString(mainString)` method but didn't assign the returned value from the method back to `mainString`. So in `UserType` method, the `mainString` value won't be updated based on the result from `NewString(mainString)`.

```cs
case 1:
    NewString(mainString);
    Console.WriteLine("test menu string: "+ mainString);
    UserType();
    break;
```

You need is to assign the result `NewString(mainString)` back to `mainString`.

```cs
mainString = NewString(mainString);
```

Comment: And agreed that what @Jeff mentioned in the comment. I don't think that there is a need to parse in the `mainString` to `NewString` method and `NewString` method with input parameter as you are providing an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a string parameter with a default value of String.Empty() or, "", to UserType like so -

```
static void UserType(string inputString = ""){...}
```

Check to see if inputString is NullOrEmpty and if it is, then Show the Main Menu. If it is not empty, then pass it into Vowel() and save its return value to a variable to be used again -

```
var userString = Vowel(inputString);
```

Then in your switch statement when the value is returned to userString, you can pass that into UserType like this-

```
UserType(userString)
```